# Is there a way to specify a minimum storage space required for installing app with OBB extension?

Tags: android, android-install-apk, apk-expansion-files

I need to unzip files from the OBB extension after Android installs the APK. After the APK install, I have to manually check in my app if there is enough space to unzip the OBB file.

I am just wondering if there is any way to not allow Android proceed with APK installation if user does not have a certain required storage space that I specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. But even if it was, there wouldn't be way of preventing the user of using more space between install and first run of your app.